# How to add mouse selected text from a textbox to list

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a multi-line `TextBox`, I want that the text which I select from `TextBox` via mouse should get added to a `List` once the mouse left click is released.

The list is defined as

```
 public List<string> PtagName = new List<string>();
```

I attached picture in reference to this question
[image]

As shown in the image, whatever I select from `TextBox` via mouse left click, it should get added to list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There you go: Hope it helps.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TextBoxLines
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public List<string> PtagName = new List<string>();

        private void textBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                if (textBox1.SelectedText.Length > 0)
                {
                    string[] lines = textBox1.SelectedText.Split('\n');
                    foreach (var line in lines)
                    {
                        PtagName.Add(line);
                    }
                }
                foreach (var line in PtagName)
                    MessageBox.Show(line);

                PtagName.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to process in a `MouseUp` event handler of your textBox:

```
private void textBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e){
  if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Left){
     if(textBox1.SelectedText.Length > 0) PtagName.Add(textBox1.SelectedText);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Handle the mouseup event and perform all your tasks there.

```
public void mytextbox_MouseUp(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e) {
   if (mytextbox.SelectionLength == 0 || e.Button != MouseButtons.Left) return;
   PtagName = mytextbox.SelectedText.Split(new [] { '\r', '\n' }).ToList(); 
}
```